# Confusion around when to compose, and when to use $

Tags: haskell

```
returnGreater :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a
returnGreater a b
  | (a > b) = a
  | otherwise = b

returnGreatest2 :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a -> (a, a)
returnGreatest2 a b c
  | (a > b) = (a, returnGreater b c)
  | otherwise = (b, returnGreater a c)

sumOfSquares :: (Num a) => (a, a) -> a
sumOfSquares (a, b) = a^2 + b^2
```

Given the above functions, I'm confused why `let x = sumOfSquares . returnGreatest2` returns

```
<interactive>:13:24: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a -> a -> (a, a)’ with ‘(c, c)’
      Expected type: a -> (c, c)
        Actual type: a -> a -> a -> (a, a)
    • Probable cause: ‘returnGreatest2’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘returnGreatest2’
      In the expression: sumOfSquares . returnGreatest2
      In an equation for ‘x’: x = sumOfSquares . returnGreatest2
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a -> c (bound at <interactive>:13:5)
```

but `sumOfSquares $ returnGreatest2 3 5 7` does the right thing.  Since the type coming out of `returnGreatest2` is the same as the type `sumOfSquares` expects, I would think I'd be able to compose them.

Comment: I'll give you a hint. What is the type of the composition operator `(.)`?

Comment: Remember that type of `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. However `returnGreatest2` takes 4 parameters so it shall be applied with 3 parameters (until its type becomes `a -> (a,a)` or as in the above type signature `(a -> b)` and only then you can apply it to composition operator. Such as  `let x = sumOfSquares . returnGreatest 2 3 5` and then `x 7` will give you the result.

Comment: Here’s a short derivation of how to convert compositions of multiple arguments like this to point-free form. `\x y z -> g ((f x y) z)` =(definition of composition)= `\x y -> g . f x y` =(rewrite in prefix)= `\x y -> ((.) g) ((f x) y)` =(definition of composition)= `\ x -> (.) g . f x` =(rewrite in prefix)= `\x -> ((.) ((.) g)) (f x)` =(definition of composition)= `(.) ((.) g) . f` =(`instance Functor ((->) a)`)= `fmap (fmap g) . f`. Here `g` = `sumOfSquares` and `f` = `returnGreatest2`. In general, to compose a 1-argument function with an *n*-argument function you need to `fmap` *n* − 1 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composition and currying can be a little confusing. `sumOfSquares . returnGreatest2` is the same as `\x -> sumOfSquares (returnGreatest2 x)`, but the type of `returnGreatest2 x` is `(Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> (a, a)`. You need to pass *all* expected arguments before you finally get a value of type `(Ord a, Num a) => (a, a)` that is acceptable by `sumOfSquares`.

On the other hand, `sumOfSquares $ returnGreatest2 3 5 7` is parsed the same as `sumOfSquares $ (returnGreatest2 3 5 7)`; the `($)` operator has lower priority than function application (or any other operator, for that matter).

To really compose the two functions, you need several layers of composition:

```
let f = ((sumOfSquares .) . ) . returnGreatest2
```

Comment: I prefer to write the point-free version as `fmap (fmap sumOfSquares) . returnGreatest2`. The `fmap` is the same as `(.)` here (in the `(->) _` functor) but imo is clearer: each `fmap` “maps over” one argument. Including extra parentheses for clarity, `fmap (fmap sumOfSquares)` is specialised to the type `(a -> a -> (a, a)) -> (a -> a -> a)`, making it composable with `returnGreatest2 :: a -> (a -> a -> (a, a))`.

Answer (score 4):

Both sides of `(.)` function are expected to be a single argument functions so it treats `returnGreatest2` as a `a -> (a -> a -> (a, a))`. But `sumOfSquares` does not accept `(a -> a -> (a, a))` as an argument. One way to do it is to use `$` like you did and apply all the arguments, but you can also state first two arguments explicitly:

```
let x a b = sumOfSquares . returnGreatest2 a b
x :: (Num c, Ord c) => c -> c -> c -> c
```

this way the types will match.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
sumOfSquares . returnGreatest2 3 5 $ 7
```

`$` has te lowest priority. `returnGreatest2 3 5` is the function `returnGreatest2` partially applied to `3` and `5` so still a function which accepts a single variable. So now you have two functions which accept a single variable:

- `sumOfSquares`
- `returnGreatest2 3 5`

You can compose them with `.` which is what `.` is meant for: composing functions with a single variable in and a single variable out.